# i have a problem with firebase connecting

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is the code :

```
DatabaseReference referenceData=FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Jobs');
referenceData.get().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {jobs.clear();

  var keys=dataSnapshot.value.keys;
var values = dataSnapshot.value;
for(var key in keys){
  Jobs jobs = Jobs(values[key]['JobName'],values[key]['JobDetails']);
}});
```

and here are the problems :

> The property 'keys' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
>
> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
>
> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

I have tried using this code :

```
DatabaseReference referenceData=FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Jobs');
referenceData.get().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {jobs.clear();
  var keys=(dataSnapshot.value! as Map<String, dynamic>).keys;
var values = dataSnapshot.value;
for(var key in keys){
  Jobs jobs = new Jobs((values! as Map<String, dynamic>)[key]['JobName'],(values! as Map<String, dynamic>)[key]['JobDetails']);
}});
```

the errors are gone but when I try to run the app I have this message :

> Invalid depfile: C:\Users\AhXoX\StudioProjects\daimond.dart_tool\flutter_build\b5bec47ddb82374feed8ecd5e7242ad4\kernel_snapshot.d
> Invalid depfile: C:\Users\AhXoX\StudioProjects\daimond.dart_tool\flutter_build\b5bec47ddb82374feed8ecd5e7242ad4\kernel_snapshot.d
> lib/main.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
> import 'dart:html';
> ^
> lib/main.dart:201:79: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'Object' which excludes null.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>   Jobs jobs = new Jobs((values! as Map<String, dynamic>)[key]['JobName'],(values! as Map<String, dynamic>)[key]['JobDetails']);
>   ^

I need help, please

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get data from firestore i mentioned the work i have done. Make fromJson factory method in Job class that takes Map<String,dynamic> as paramter just like that i am fetching user from firestore.

```
 factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
    uId: json["uID"],
    name: json["name"],
    image: json["image"],
    number: json["number"],
    status: json["status"],
    typing: json["typing"],
    online: json["online"],
  );
```

now we will get all user from firestore.

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getAppContacts() async {
try {
  final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").get();
  return data.docs.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e.data())).toList();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  throw Exception(e.toString());
}
```

}

In your method i think you are passing extra [key] try to remove it that might be work.